# How display tag a from behind to front?

Tags: html, css

I create a menu has sub-menu at top of page and a slide image under of menu.

Result: Please reference to image file attached:
submenu is displaying behind of Slide image:

[image]

How can move submenu display front of slide image?

This is my css of  top menu:
But If i add slide image , sub menu display behind.

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu a {
  color: #4C9CF1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

#menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about">Product</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup">SignUp</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- display the slider -->
<div>
  <div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="">
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x768" alt="1" title="1" />
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- End -->
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

add `z-index: 100;` so its work

```
.sub-menu {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu a {
  color: #4C9CF1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

#menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">Product</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="signup">SignUp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- display the slider -->
  <div>
    <div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:0 auto;">
      <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="">
        <li><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="1" title="1" />
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the z-index higher for the item that you want to show in-front.

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu a {
  color: #4C9CF1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#menu a:hover {
  color: #444;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

#menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about">Product</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup">SignUp</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<body>
<!-- display the slider -->
<div>
  <div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="">
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1024x768" alt="1" title="1" />
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
<!-- End -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu {
        z-index:9000
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu {

    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position：relative
    z-index:99;
}
```

try this,must add position